# Real vector bundles over $S^1$

Tags: vector-bundles, smooth-manifolds

> Prove that for every real vector bundle over $S^1$ there exist open connected subsets $U_1,U_2 \subset S^1$ with $U_1 \cup U_2=S^1$ such that $E$ is trivial over $U_1$ and over $U_2$.

I need an **elementary** proof of this fact. I know that v.b. over contractible spaces are trivial, but we do **not** have seen this result during lecture about smooth manifolds, and we are supposed to prove this fact.

Other than basic definitions, we covered sections, frames, whitney sums, inner products, and the facts that every bundles is a subbundle of a trivial bundle over the same base space. With so few *instruments* I do not know where to start to prove this fact.

Comment: Well, how is a vector bundle defined over a manifold? Doesn't the definition require that *locally* it has to be trivial?

Comment: @Berci yes, but other than obtaining a finite covering over which it is trivial, how can I reduce it to be only 2 components? I thought about that, but I didn't found a way to *glue* some of the local trivialisation to obtain only 2 of them which covers all of $S^1$

Comment: Well, for this you need to prove that vector bundles over intervals are trivial. Then you can take unions of consecutive intervals on the circle unless it goes around.

Comment: Or I can easily use the fact that as a manifold, S^1 is covered by two segments let's say... ok, so I need to work on how to prov that a vector bundle over an interval is trivial... without using "powerful" theorems :(